# Understanding context and app methods in NUXT

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, bugsnag

I am trying to use bugsnagClient and its notify method in `plugins/axios.js` I have this code in `plugins/bugsnag.js`

```
import Vue from "vue"
import bugsnag from "@bugsnag/js"
import bugsnagVue from "@bugsnag/plugin-vue"

// const bugsnagClient = bugsnag(`${process.env.BUGSNAG_API_KEY}`)
var bugsnagClient = bugsnag({
  apiKey: "",
  notifyReleaseStages: ["production"]
})

bugsnagClient.use(bugsnagVue, Vue)
```

I want to attach a method to `app` or `context` as

```
export default ({ app }, inject) => {
  function bugsnagNotify(error) {
    return bugsnagClient.notify(new Error(error))
  }
  // Set the function directly on the context.app object
  app.bugsnagNotify = bugsnagNotify
}
```

And I want to use it in `plugins/axios.js`

```
export default function({ store, app }) {
  if (store.getters.token) {
    console.log(app.bugsnagNotify("ss"))
    app.$axios.setToken(store.getters.token, "Bearer")
  } else {
    //app.$bugsnag.notify(new Error("Bearer tooken is missing in Axios request."))
  }
}
```

In this file, when I do console.log for just `app`

I can see `bugsnagNotify: ƒ bugsnagNotify(error)`

but when I call `app.bugsnagNotify("error")` I only get error such as `VM73165:37 TypeError: app.bugsnagNotify is not a function`

I have also tried this in `plugins/bugsnag.js`

```
export default (ctx, inject) => {
  inject('bugsnag', bugsnagClient)
}
```

I only get an error as

```
app.$bugsnag.notify(new Error("Bearer tooken is missing in Axios request."))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are injecting into context inside one plugin and want to use that function inside another, you need to make sure that the plugin in which you are injecting comes first inside `nuxt.config.js`

```js
...
plugins: [
  '~/plugins/bugsnag.js',
  '~/plugins/axios.js'
],
...
```